# Custom Lists: how to retrieve 3 most recent item submissions

Tags: list, sharepoint-2007, caml

I have currently 2 custom SharePoint lists. One represents questions, the other one answers.

Both lists have the default columns in place: ID, modified by date and username.

The requirement is now to get the 3 most recent items (indepent of the list) or submissions.

What is the easiest way to do this using CAML queries?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

[Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28office.12%29.aspx)

[Query element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms471093%28office.12%29.aspx)

Read up on those two CAML structures.